# Phonegap Does httpRequest correctly in browser but not in phone

Tags: cordova, http, ionic-framework, get, phonegap

I have the next code:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.youtube.com");

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

       document.getElementById('master').innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;

    }
};

xhttp.send();
```

I try the same with google and Facebook and it worked fine in browser and phone but youtube only works in Browser ¿What happened?

pd: browser = desktop browser

**pd: pd: It enter in the if and does the innerHTML but in the phone the responseText doesn't return anything**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of the User Agent as `http://www.youtube.com` redirects to `http://m.youtube.com` the loading of the www is probably canceled and just return the empty response.

I've added this preference on my config.xml to use this desktop user agent and I get a response now.

`<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" />`

Comment: the status works fine, it enter in the if and does the innerHTML but in the phone the responseText doesn't return anything

Comment: Thanks! works when I emulated this in a virtual device, but not in the Phonegap app :( ... At least it's something. :)

Comment: yeah, your config.xml values won't affect the Phonegap Developer app because the Phonegap Developer app is a Phonegap app with it's own config.xml https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/blob/master/config.xml